# Salto de linea al escribir una linea en un archivo txt

Tags: python-3.7

Estoy tratando de escribir una linea en un archivo txt con el siguiente codigo.

file.write(playerName.lower() +":" +"500" +":"+ "3"+":"+ "5" +"\n")

El problema es que cuando quiero traer la informacion del archivo para mostrarla el salto de linea se agrega al ultimo elemento es decir el ultimo elemento de la linea es 5\n y necesito que  me traiga solo el 5. Que puedo hacer para quitar ese salto de linea cuando traiga la informacion?

Comment: La mejor forma que se me ocurre, para evitar cargar todo el archivo en memoria, es usar linea.rstrip("\n"). Esto elimina todos los saltos de linea al final de una cadena. Si, opino que Python debería tener una forma de leer cada linea excluyendo los saltos de linea, pero (aun?) no lo tiene.

Comment: Documentación del método rstrip de las cadenas: https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip